# spring boot without tomcat in a standalone jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a project structure with three jar files. All are loaded into one classpath and then get executed. I am using the spring core, jpa and hibernate. `@Services`/`@Autowired` are working fine, as well as Entities and Repositories (all on a mysql database).

Now I want that the project can send and receive messages over network/internet. So I asked some people how I could achieve this without breaking my current structure. And I was told that spring-boot is the architecture for me because I do not need a web server (tomcat or glassfish) for it.

But now I am not sure if this is correct because I did not find any sources that say the same thing. Because of that I tried implementing it in order to verify it myself.
The important changes I made to my project (all `pom.xml` files and my configuration class) can be found here: http://84.141.90.123:9910/

From what I read I need the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation for spring boot. This is a equivalent to `@Configuration`, `@ComponentScan`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@EnableWebMvc`.
The first two are already in my structure. But when I add the last two annotations, I get different errors:

- When I add `@EnableAutoConfiguration` I get

  ```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
  ```
- When I add `@EnableWebMvc` I get

  ```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
  ```

From my bad english knollage, the `@EnableWebMvc` error seems to say that the application needs a web server (tomcat or glassfish).
So is the main statement wrong and I can not start spring boot without a web server?

Because I do not use any xml files and/or property files for spring (they did not worked), I only rely on java code based configuration for spring, jpa and hibernate. And therefore there are only very few tutorials/threads with help. Most of the time they just say `add thi or add that to your xml` but because I don't have them, it is a little pain in the ass.

Also I compile with aspectj, so I can not use the spring compile parent. And also I am not able to manipulate the main class/method, because the main class is in an outer jar file that is not programmed by me.

So concrete:

1. Can a spring boot application in a standalone jar run without a web server wrapping it?
2. If yes, what am I doing wrong? Am I missing a dependency, an annotation or a configuration?

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. You are trying to run a web app without a webserver that is never gonna happen. Your knowledge on what `@SpringBootApplication` is/does is wrong. It doesn't include `@EnableWebMvc`. The `@EnableWebMvc` is added through auto-configuration and only if certain web related classes are detected. Just add `@SpringBootApplication` and make sure you have the proper maven plugin and dependencies. If you want to expose endpoints you need a server, Spring Boot ships with an embedded one so you don't need to deploy it. I guess that is the main misconception here.

Comment: I am very sorry, but I think I do not understand your answer. So you telling me to add `@SpringBootApplication`. But from what I read, I must add this to the main class. And I can not change that method because it is in another jar file that is not programmed by me. Or can I just add the annotation to my JpaConfig Class? And further on, what do you mean with "expose endpoints"? Is spring boot the architecture I am searching for or not? receiving and sending http GET/POST Requests from my current jar projects is the only goal I try to achieve.

Comment: How do you expect to receive GET/POST requests if you don't have any container? I suggest reading some documentation and get a basic understanding on what Spring Boot is and what it can do. You can simply add the annotations, but yu need something that bootstraps the spring application, ie `SpringApplication` without it nothing will happen.

Comment: @Deinum: In my case the HTTP container is the AWS API Gateway. It sends the bytes to a Lambda and I still need a controller to handle the call. No need for an HTTP server

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive messages over HTTP(ie run a REST API) then you need a web server.
If you just want to send messages over HTTP then you only need a HTTP client.

Spring-boot has the the option of running an embedded web server(tomcat by default), you don't need to run a separate application server.

To work out your issues with your build I would start with generating a project using [spring initializr](https://start.spring.io/).

You can select the dependencies you want(try using the advanced version link at the bottom), and it will build a maven/gradle project for you with the right structure, build file and compatible dependencies.

Comment: In my case AWS API Gateway is sending the bytes and I still need a controller to handle the call. No need for an HTTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Change  :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ActiveMqApplication.class, args); 
}
```

to  :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(ActiveMqApplication.class)
       .web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run(args);
}
```